# Scala Spark IndexedRowMatrix returns wrong number of rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.1.0 with Scala 2.11.2. I have created an IndexedRowMatrix, from an IndexedRowRDD, with 4 rows and 6 columns. When I print the lines of the matrix I get this output:

```
IndexedRow(4,[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0])
IndexedRow(2,[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0])
IndexedRow(3,[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
IndexedRow(1,[0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0])
```

When I print the number of rows however the result is 5. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because matrices are indexed from 0. Spark assumes that the input is correct and number of rows is max(index) + 1.